# Quill WYSIWYG editor - adding attributes to buttons

Tags: wysiwyg, quill

How do I add attributes to the buttons in a Quill-base WYSIWIG editor?

This is my code

```html
<div class="quill-wrapper">
  <div id="toolbar" class="ql-toolbar-container toolbar">
    <div class="ql-format-group">
      <span class="ql-bold ql-format-button"></span>
      <span class="ql-italic ql-format-button"></span>
      <span class="ql-strike ql-format-button"></span>
      <span class="ql-underline ql-format-button"></span>
      <span class="ql-link ql-format-button"></span>
      <span class="ql-format-button ql-color"></span>
      <span class="ql-format-separator"></span>
      <select class="ql-font">
        <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
      </select>
      <select class="ql-size">
        <option value="small">Small</option>
        <option value="normal">Normal</option>
        <option value="large">Large</option>
      </select>

    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="postDesc" name="postDesc" value="pavitar dua">
  <!-- Create the editor container -->
  <div style="height:300px" class="form-control" id="editor" name="editor">
    <div>Hello World!</div>
    <div>Some initial <b>bold</b> text</div>
    <div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="counter" id="counter"></div>
</div>
```

Now if I were to add colours to `<span class="ql-format-button ql-color"></span>`, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What is wrong with these examples?  http://quilljs.com/examples/  But seriously, questions asking for links to off-site resources are off-topic.

Comment: @StephenC I'm particularly looking for documentation on how to add buttons and their attributes, check edit.

Comment: @stephenC do you suggest closing/rephrasing this question?

Comment: I have retracted my downvote.  But yes, I think you should rephrase your question.  Make sure that the question is asking about what you really want to know about ... not just "the examples are bad, give be good ones".  Start by deleting *everything* before the "EDIT" ... and make the title more self explanatory.

Comment: @StephenC thankyou :) I made necessary changes

Comment: Asking for "tips and tricks" is worse than your original title.  I have updated your question to ask the question that you said you wanted answering.  See what I mean now?

Comment: thank you. I will keep this in mind for future questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colors in Quill is a selectable format so you would add it exactly the same way you added font and size. Ex.

```
<select class="ql-color">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="#00f">Blue</option>
  <option value="rgb(255,255,0)">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

More details here: http://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/